# What is the best video converter software to make files to be played in iPhone & iPod?

Tags: video, ipod, iphone, convert

What is the best video converter software to make files to be played in iPhone & iPod?

How can I convert video to be played on iPhone & iPod?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php). As you see it has iPod and iPhone configurationss (presets) by default. :)

[image: Handbrake]

Answer (score 1):

You can also try Arista Transcoder([image: Install arista][arista](http://packages.ubuntu.com/arista)). It's available in repository and it looks like it supports Apple things(like iPhone, iPod, iPad and so on). (Sorry for non-english screenshot)

[image: Arista Transcoder]

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Mobile Media Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.php). Really simple and ideal for converting videos for Apple Devices.
[image]

[image]